# How to edit the value of a table data from input field

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, conditional-statements, dom-events

I have a small form with Name and Phone number, its a simple phonebook. Every new element from the input will appear below in a table, next to the name and phone number there are 2 buttons, an edit and a delete button. The delete button works, but I am having problem editing the added items.

When I press the edit button, I managed to display that rows value(name and phone number) to be inserted back to the input fields where I could edit them, but something is missing, a little guide or hint will be greatly apprecciated.

Here is the markup.

```js
// Get all the elements to interact with the DOM
let form = document.querySelector('.form');
let inputMessage = document.getElementById('inputMessage');
let table = document.querySelector('.book-table');
let tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
let nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
let numberInput = document.getElementById('number');
let submitBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let editBtn = document.querySelector('.edit-btn');
let deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete-btn');


// Function to manipulate elements
function addNumber() {
    if (nameInput.value != '' && numberInput.value != '') {
        let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
        let firstCol = document.createElement('td');
        let secondCol = document.createElement('td');
        let thirdCol = document.createElement('td');
        let fourthCol = document.createElement('td');
        let editBtn = document.createElement('button');
        let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
        firstCol.innerHTML = nameInput.value;
        secondCol.innerHTML = numberInput.value;
        editBtn.className = 'edit-btn';
        deleteBtn.className = 'delete-btn';
        editBtn.innerHTML = 'Edit';
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
        newRow.appendChild(firstCol)
        newRow.appendChild(secondCol)
        newRow.appendChild(thirdCol);
        newRow.appendChild(fourthCol);
        thirdCol.appendChild(editBtn);
        fourthCol.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        nameInput.value = '';
        numberInput.value = '';
        inputMessage.style.visibility = 'visible';
        inputMessage.innerHTML = 'Contact Added Successfully';
        inputMessage.classList.add('message');
        inputMessage.classList.remove('error-message');
    } else {
        inputMessage.style.visibility = 'visible';
        inputMessage.innerHTML = 'Please fill out all required fields';
        inputMessage.classList.remove('message');
        inputMessage.classList.add('error-message');
    }
}

function deleteBook(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.className == 'delete-btn') {
        // the table row with the 4 td elements
        // console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
        const td = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (td) {
            tableBody.removeChild(td);
        }
    }
}

function editBook(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.className == 'edit-btn') {
        const td = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        // console.log(td);
        let editName = td.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
        let editNumber = td.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
        nameInput.value = editName.innerHTML;
        // console.log(editName.innerHTML)
        editName.innerHTML = nameInput.value;
        numberInput.value = editNumber.innerHTML;
        console.log(nameInput)
        console.log(nameInput.value)

    }
}

// Event listeners
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addNumber);

numberInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    // console.log(e);
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // console.log('you hit enter');
        addNumber();
    }
});

nameInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // console.log('you hit enter');
        addNumber();
    }
});

table.addEventListener('click', editBook);

table.addEventListener('click', deleteBook);
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Phone Book</h1>
        <form action="" class="form">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required autocomplete="off">
            <label for="number">Phone</label>
            <input type="number" id="number" name="number" required>
        </form>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Add Contact</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Add error and success message -->
    <div id="inputMessage" class="message">
    </div>
    <table class="book-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I would need help with the editBook function, sorry if I pasted too much Code!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out with this code snippet

```js
if (e.target && e.target.className == 'edit-btn') {
        e.target.innerHTML = 'Save';
        clickCount++;
        const td = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        // console.log(td);
        let editName = td.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
        let editNumber = td.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
        if (clickCount > 1) {
            // change HTML back to edit
            e.target.innerHTML = 'Edit';
            // set clickCount back to 0
            clickCount = 0;
        }
        // save the values from the input in the same table row
        let tmp = nameInput.value;
        console.log(tmp, nameInput.value);
        nameInput.value = editName.innerHTML;
        console.log(nameInput.value, editName.innerHtml);
        // console.log(editName.innerHTML)
        editName.innerHTML = tmp;
        console.log(editName.innerHTML, tmp);
        let tmp2 = numberInput.value;
        numberInput.value = editNumber.innerHTML;
        editNumber.innerHTML = tmp2;
    }
```